# i need the code for making the fancy box displaceable

Tags: html, fancybox

Here is the story:

on my web www.galeriapunto.com I am using a fancy box on the home page to show the latest news upfront.

I need for users to be able to move this window where they feel most comfortable, but I can't seem to find how to do this. Can you guys let me know whether this is possible and if yes what code should I use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a link for [drag and drop with fancy box](http://jquery.diaz-cornen.com/fancybox/index_dragfancybox.html). Disclaimer - I have never used it, I just googled it.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it works, and if it does I will put it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You need the [easydrag jQuery plugin](http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/07/14/easydrag-jquery-plugin/)

The [link with the example](http://jquery.diaz-cornen.com/fancybox/index_dragfancybox.html) provided by @myHeadHurts (thanks), I wrote it back in 2009 for fancybox v1.2.x using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // add drag and drop functionality to fancybox
    $("#fancy_outer").easydrag();
});
</script>
```

It worked fine until v1.3.1, but tweaking the script like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // add drag and drop functionality to fancybox
    $("#fancybox-outer").easydrag();
});
</script>
```

However, it works "buggy" with the script above with fancybox v1.3.4 (close button and nav arrows are misplaced) so I stopped using it (no time to fix the code or find a workaround).

I haven't tested it with v2.x but my guess is that it won't work out of the box. The easyDrag plugin hasn't been updated since 2008.